# Angular Whitespace Validator working wrong

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms, angular-validation

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My whitespacer validator works wrong.

TS:

```
this.personalForm = this.form.group({
      firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), CustomValidators.validateCharacters]],
      lastname: ['', [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]], //CustomValidators.validateCharacters,
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      dateOfBirth: ['', [Validators.required]],
      gender: ['', [Validators.required]],
})
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="field-sizing">
              <input matInput required placeholder="{{ 'REGISTRATION.LASTNAME' | translate }}" name="lastname"
                formControlName="lastname" type="name"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': g.lastname.touched && g.lastname.errors }" />
                <mat-error class="invalid-feedback"
                *ngIf="g.lastname.touched && g.lastname.errors && g.lastname.errors.whitespace">
                {{ 'REGISTRATION.LASTNAME' | translate }} 
              </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Validator Function:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function NoWhitespaceValidator(): ValidatorFn {

  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {

     // messy but you get the idea
    let isWhitespace = (control.value || '').trim().length === 0;
    let isValid = !isWhitespace;
    return isValid ? null : { 'whitespace': true }

  };
}
```

I log to the console and it was only reacting when nothing was inserted or when only whitespaces are inserted at the beginning. That does not give me anything because I want to check if there are leading or ending whitespaces and then show an error message.

Comment: Could just use regex `let isWhitespace = /^\s|\s$/.test(control.value);`

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you. I'm not good in this regex stuff. @penleychan

Answer (score 1):

I think you want it to look more like this,

```
let isWhitespace = (control.value || '').trim().length !== (control.value || '').length;
```

this way you're checking if the trimmed length is the same as the non trimmed length, this would indicate if there is white space before or after effectively, as  the trim function returns the string with white space trimmed off the beginning and end, so if the lengths aren't the same, whitespace has been trimmed.

Comment: This does not work. Now it not even recognizes only whitespaces. Just empty field gets recognized.

Comment: sorry, the negating logic confused me for a sec, this should be edited to be correct. returns true if it has leading or trailing white space, false if it does not. This should be what you want.